# In Google Analytics, is it possible to track users separately by whether or not theyre logged in?

Tags: google-analytics

For example, a logged in user will always reach my /customer/info page after logging in, so can i separate my Google analytics result based on whether or not users of my site reached that page?

I've contacted google support many times, and they all said this is impossible. But i feel like they were just trying to not help me. they always said i need to redirect the customer to some kind of thankyou.hmtl page before they're brought to their profile page, but why do i need this thankyou.html page when a user is always brough to their profile page after logging in and my user profile page is also an html page (cshtml) and start the tracking there?

a few result from google says this is the code i want but im not sure where to impement that.

```
if (isset($userId)) {
  $gacode = "ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', { 'userId': '%s' });";
  echo sprintf($gacode, $userId);
} else {
  $gacode = "ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y');";
  echo sprintf($gacode);
}
```

i expect a way for Google Analytics to give me two separate data based on whether or not a user is logged in. i want to see the different pages a logged in users might visit vs non logged in users

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the userId tracking (similar to your example) and then create a view for the userId (from the Property settings ). In this view you will get the data only of the users who have logged in (the data where the userId is sent to Analytics).

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123666?hl=en&ref_topic=3123660

Comment: hi michelle, that you for your reply. i talked to ym boss and he said there is no suchparameters like user ID that our website tracks , so google analytics cant grab that. however, doesnt google track each user session?

isnt there a way to separate analytics to sessions that contains visit to the user profile page (meaning they logged in) and sessions where they do not (meaning they do not login/guest users)??

Comment: You can use custom dimension. Configure a custom dimension at hit level with 'loggedOut' value as default, then when the user do the login (and for as long as it is logged) changes its value to 'loggedIn'. In this way you can see in Analytics the pages visited when a user is logged in and when he is not logged.